# django http response with csv and html

Tags: python, django, csv

I try to find a way to process some data in a django url, and return it in a csv format, I found [here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.9/howto/outputting-csv/) a way of doing so.

it works, but the thing is that when I get the csv, I also get the following error:

```
TypeError at /game/play
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
Request Method: GET
Request URL:    http://127.0.0.1:8000/game/play
Django Version: 1.9.2
Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value:    
__init__() got an unexpected keyword argument 'text'
Exception Location: /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/django/http/response.py in __init__, line 283
Python Executable:  /usr/bin/python
Python Version: 2.7.6
Python Path:    
['/home/s/djangostuff/mysite',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/plat-x86_64-linux-gnu',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-tk',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-old',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/lib-dynload',
 '/usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/PILcompat',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/gtk-2.0',
 '/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/ubuntu-sso-client']
Server time:    Wed, 17 Feb 2016 10:14:31 +0000
```

I can't find a way of returning a response that contains a csv and a regular textual and\or some nice html page to go along with my csv.

the code is here:

```
 def play(request):
    l = ['what','the','h',2123]
    response = HttpResponse(content_type = 'text/csv') 
    response['content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename="somthing.csv"'
    writer = csv.writer(response) 
    writer.writerow(l)
    writer.writerow(l)
    return response
```

Comment: It's not clear what you mean. You can only return one response at a time.

Comment: Plus, the error does not match your code; you don't use a `text` argument anywhere, and there's nowhere you are actually trying to do what you describe.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are reading from a `csv` file which have title in first row, you should skip the first row then read it

Comment: thanks, that i know, but the question is how to send back a csv file and also get in the same time, a nice html http response...

Comment: @captainshai You mean, you wanna respond a `csv` file and redirect on the new page?

Comment: End point has just one response, you can handle it on frontend i think, additionally,  you are changing header type to csv, you can handle that by your web server, when download complete, then redirect